# NiceScroll not working on Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I'm trying to get NiceScroll to work so that the whole body of the page scrolls, not just individual divs. 
It's not working. I've searched through similar forums with no work around. Here is my current code so far:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>

<script>
$("html").mouseover(function() {
    $("#html").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
</script>
```

I've tried `var nice = $("html").niceScroll();` as well, and it doesn't work either.

I also have these scripts at the bottom of the page, incase you need to know of other plugins:

```
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.quicksand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see a $('html') and a $('#html') - # is messing up the second one. Can it be as simple as this?

Comment: I didn't even notice that! But I corrected it, and it STILL does not work.

Comment: your question saved my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try this:

```
$("html").mouseover(function() {
    $("html").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

it works without errors on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kswf5v65/), so I guess that's just the # in your query. What result did you expect?

Comment: that jsfiddle is not working for me.. whats the `console.log('bau');` and `console.log('miao');` for?

Comment: They're just there to show that the mouseover is triggered. Does it print anything on your console? Because if it doesn't, then @Eterm is right - you need to change mouseover with document.ready ...

Comment: Okay.... well i run the script and nothing shows... i changed MY script to `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").getNiceScroll().resize();
});`, and it still does not work.

Comment: [Check this out...](http://jsfiddle.net/kswf5v65/2/) Maybe there's something wrong with the getNiceScroll() function? Can I ask you why you use it in combination with resize(), btw?

Comment: Thank you for the help, I actually just figured it out - first i had an error calling my jquery library, then it only worked using the document.ready.... but it is fixed and working now! thanks!

Comment: your answer saved my day :)